Using a Webauthn authenticate request to return an oauth token
I have a PWA with a Drupal backend.
I'm using simple oauth.
Making a request such as:
{
  grant_type: 'password',
  client_id: 'someClientId',
  username: 'example@test.com',
  password: password,
}

to: /oauth/token will result in a token.
However I would like to use a passkey to authenticate instead.
The closest module to a working solution I've found is Decoupled Passkeys
I can make a request (with jsonrpc) to user.authenticate_request which if all is successful end with this code:
user_login_finalize($account);
return json_encode($account);

So as I'm using a custom user class via hook_entity_type_build I can make it implement JsonSerializable and provide a jsonSerialize method to fetch an oauth token which will then get returned after the passkey has been authenticated.
I've found no way of programmatically getting an oauth token so I've resorted to just making a request.
However then I need the users plaintext password.
So I've resorted to the crazy scheme of saving the users current password hash, creating and setting a new random password, using this to get an oauth token, and then setting the users password hash back to it's original value.
So my user class contains:
public function jsonSerialize(): array {
  return [
    'id' => $this->id(),
    'token' => $this->getOauthToken(),
  ];
}

private function getOauthToken() {
  $clientId = 'someClientId';

  $userOriginalPasswordHash = $this->getPassword();

  $tempPassword = 'imagine a service to generate a password here';

  $this->setPassword($tempPassword);
  $this->save();

  $response = NULL;

  try {
    $base_url = 'host.docker.internal';
    $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->post($base_url . '/oauth/token', [
      'verify' => TRUE,
      'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'username' => $this->getEmail(),
        'password' => $tempPassword,
      ],
      'headers' => [
        'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents();
  }
  catch (\Exception $exception) {
    return $exception->getMessage();
  }
  finally {
    $this->setPasswordFromHash($userOriginalPasswordHash);
  }

  return $response;
}

private function setPasswordFromHash(string $hash): void {
  $connection = \Drupal::database();

  try {
    $connection->update('users_field_data')->fields(['pass' => $hash])->condition('uid', $this->id())->execute();
  }
  catch (\Exception $exception) {
    // log error - this would be bad as users password is now broken.
  }
}

Whilst this is 100% working it seems like the wrong way to be doing things.
Should I be making a new custom grant type instead? I have tried to research this but have not found any good resources on this.
Is there an easier way to programmatically get an oauth token?

Or would JWT be an easier option?
